# Database table won't show in codeigniter /xampp

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter, xampp

My database table wont show like it does on scentedlightsllc.com/livetable. not sure if there is another way to connect to xampp localhost database that i've created.

This is my config.php file

```
<?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "members";

    $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) 
          or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
          mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

?>
```

below is my index.php file

```
<div align='center'>

  <table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1' id='mytable'>
    <tr align='center'>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

<?php
error_reporting(0);
include('config.php');
$sql="select * from member";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $fname=$row['fname'];
    $lname=$row['lname'];
    $email=$row['email'];

    echo "<tr  class='edit_tr' id='$id'>
              <td class='edit_td'>
                <span class='text' id='one_$id' >$fname</span>
                <input type='text' class='editbox_search' id='one_input_$id' value='$fname' >
              </td>

              <td class='edit_td'>
                <span class='text' id='two_$id' >$lname</span>
                <input type='text' class='editbox_search' id='two_input_$id' value='$lname' >
              </td>

              <td class='edit_td'>
                <span class='text' id='three_$id' >$email</span>
                <input type='text' class='editbox_search' id='three_input_$id' value='$email' >
              </td>   

                <td class='edit_td' >
                  <a href='#'  class='edit_btn'>Edit</a>
                  <a href='#'  class='update' >Update</a>
                  <a href='#'  class='cancel' >Cancel</a>
                  <a href='#' class='delete' > Delete </a>
               </td>
        </tr>";  
     }             
?>

 <tr>
      <td><input type='text' id='fname' placeholder='firstname'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='lname' placeholder='lastname'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='email' placeholder='email'/></td>
      <td  ><a href='#' id='add' >ADD</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use codeigniter database.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html in the config file and then load autoload the library? and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Use models to get items from database http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: thanks wolfgang... good idea ,, works great now :)